# Rebind a dropdownlist in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater, viewstate

I have a dropdownlist in a repeater. I want whenever a postback has been raised, then rebind the dropdownlist.

The problem is, when I debbug this thing, the code did run through the ddl.databind(), but for some resons, the dropdownlist still load the list and selected value from the original viewstate. I know that because if I set the ddl's EnableViewState as "false", i can rebind the ddl properly.

Any suggestions?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="reEventsDataTypeOthers" runat="server" Visible="false">
...
<ItemTemplate>
...
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEventSessionLocation" runat="server" CssClass="ddlControlS1L" Title="Location" EnableViewState="true"/>
```

Codebehinde (I tried to bind it in _ItemCreated and _ItemDataBound, but both faied):

```
void reEventsDataTypeOthers_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                return;
            FSIDropDownList ddl = e.Item.FindControl("ddlEventSessionLocation") as FSIDropDownList;
            if (ddl != null && ddl.SelectedValue != "NOTSET")
            {
                ddl.DataSource = EventLocations;
                ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
                ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
                ddl.DataBind();
                ddl.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Not Set", "NOTSET"));
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE, Problem solved**:

What I did is put the dropdownlist bind code in this repeater's prerender event method, thus can overwrite the viewstate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the drop down list is probably being overwritten by the viewstate, make sure to populate it after page init has completed, in the page load for example. See the page cycle here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx